# Не добавляет записи в MySQL из PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Код PHP выводит информацию из БД правильно, но не может записать в неё.
Никаких ошибок не выводит при добавлении записи, возвращает эту же страницу с тем же содержимым.
Основной файл:

```
<?php //sqltest.php
require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);
if (!$db_server) die("невозможно подключиться к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)
or die("невозможно выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());
if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
$isbn = get_post('isbn');
$query = "DELETE FROM class WHERE isbn='$isbn'";
if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
echo "Сбой при удалении данных: $query <br/>" .
mysql_error() . "<br/><br/>";
}
if (isset($_POST['autor']) &&
isset($_POST['title']) &&
isset($_POST['category']) &&
isset($_POST['year']) &&
isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
$autor      = get_post('autor');
$title      = get_post('title');
$category   = get_post('category');
$year       = get_post('year');
$isbn       = get_post('isbn');
$query = "INSERT INTO class VALUES" .
"('$autor', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";
if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
echo "Сбой при добавлении данных: $query <br/>" .
mysql_error() . "<br/><br/>";
}
echo <<<_END
<form action="sqltest.php" mathod="post"><pre>
Autor <input type="text" name="autor" />
Title <input type="text" name="title" />
Category <input type="text" name="category" />
Year <input type="text" name="year" />
ISBN <input type="text" name="isbn" />
<input type="submit" value="Add record" />
</pre></form>
_END;
$query = "SELECT * FROM class";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) die("Сбой при доступе к базе данных: " . mysql_error());
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)
{
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
echo <<<_END
<pre>
Autor $row[0]
Title $row[1]
Category $row[2]
Year $row[3]
ISBN $row[4]
</pre>
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes" />
<input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]" />
<input type="submit" value="Delete record" /></form>
_END;
}
mysql_close($db_server);
function get_post($var)
{
return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

Файл получения доступа к БД:

```
<?php // login.php
$db_hostname = '127.0.0.1';
$db_database = 'test';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = '555555';
?>
```

Comment: Возможно у вас не валидные данные для записи в базу,  проверьте типы данных которые записываются в каждую колонку

Comment: При добавлении записи через терминал всё нормально. Через PHP - нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

у вас $_POST[...] проверки, а форма передается через GET, поскольку вы опечатку сделали
`mathod="post"`

Comment: Спасибо. То есть, по умолчанию - через GET?

Comment: да. и да, если вы видите параметры в адресной строке - значит ушел GET